# AWS API - why is ResourceType required in --tag-specifications; Doesn't API action imply the ResourceType?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've came across AWS API documentation. Any time I want to add name to the resource I am free to do so, by using the `--tag-specifications`, however why am I forced to provide `ResourceType` when it's seemingly clear what resource I am modifying/creating?

E.g.
`aws ec2 create-route-table --tag-specifications "ResourceType=route-table,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=My route table}]" --vpc-id ${VPC_ID}`

Is there any situation where I would provide any other `ResourceType` here?

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-route-table.html mentions:

```
ResourceType -> (string) - The type of resource to tag. Currently, the resource types that support tagging on creation are: capacity-reservation | carrier-gateway | client-vpn-endpoint | customer-gateway | dedicated-host | dhcp-options | egress-only-internet-gateway | elastic-ip | elastic-gpu | export-image-task | export-instance-task | fleet | fpga-image | host-reservation | image | import-image-task | import-snapshot-task | instance | internet-gateway | ipv4pool-ec2 | ipv6pool-ec2 | key-pair | launch-template | local-gateway-route-table-vpc-association | placement-group | prefix-list | natgateway | network-acl | network-interface | reserved-instances |route-table | security-group | snapshot | spot-fleet-request | spot-instances-request | snapshot | subnet | traffic-mirror-filter | traffic-mirror-session | traffic-mirror-target | transit-gateway | transit-gateway-attachment | transit-gateway-multicast-domain | transit-gateway-route-table | volume |vpc | vpc-peering-connection | vpc-endpoint (for interface and gateway endpoints) | vpc-endpoint-service (for AWS PrivateLink) | vpc-flow-log | vpn-connection | vpn-gateway .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because not all the resources support tags, and they need a way to differentiate that which can be tagged.

As there is a separate resource group tagging API

[TagResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_TagResources.html), So my guess the tag creation API call is eventually being made and `ResourceType` is being passed in the API call to the respective the resource group tagging API and it has a limitation, which resources can be tagged.

That's the only possible justification, and your point is totally reasonable, API action should be a hint to what is the type of resources being created and if needed should pass/proxy that information further down the chanin.

[TagSpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_TagSpecification.html)